# looping / chaining multiple Function.applyThen() or Function.apply() using for or for-each loop

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

i have a generic method that takes a var-args type Function and an input and i want to process the first Function and input then the output will be chained by `Function.apply(Function.apply(input))` or chained by `andThen()` like `Function.andThen(Function)` and the output function will take the input and process it.

```
private static <Input,Output> Output flow(Input input, Function<Input,Output>... functions) {
    Function<Input,Output> outputFunction;
    for (int i =0; i<functions.length; i++) {
        outputFunction = functions[i].andThen((Function<? super Output, ? extends Output>) functions[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Q1: is it possible using function.apply(input);

Q2: is it possible using function.andThen(function);

Q3: any other solution available for this same problem?

Q4: what would be the best practice if i want to solve this type of chaining issue?

Comment: Aside from not compiling, this function doesn't make type sense: to chain functions, you have to be able to pass the output of one as the input to the next. This means that `Input` and `Output` have to be the same types.

Comment: I think that you'll run into generic type mismatches very quickly. That's because the result of the first function is the input to the second, so these need to match. For two functions you need not one but three generic types: `<I, M, O> O flow(I input, Function<I, M> f1, Function<M, O> f2)`. The more functions, the more generic types are needed. My advice: just chain the functions where they come from, because at that point their generic types are still known.

Comment: "just chain the functions where they come from" yes, this. But then, if you're composing the functions outside this method, you may as well also _apply_ the composed function outside this method, making it redundant.

Comment: This method also doesn't make sense because you would end up with `outputFunction` being the composition of the penultimate and last function (ignoring the off-by-one indexing error), rather than a chain of all the functions.

Comment: It is not possible to chain a bunch of `Function<Input, Output>` together. Think about it: the first function would produce `Output`, and the second function would need to take in an `Output` (not `Input`!) for this to work! In general, it is possible to chain `Function<T1, T2>`, `Function<T2, T3>`, `Function<T3, T4>` and so on together to produce `Function<T1, Tn>`, but it is not possible to chain a list of functions of the same type `Function<T1, T2>`, unless `T1 ` and `T2` are the same.

Comment: @AndyTurner its an example what i want to achieve.

Comment: @MohibulHassan I can only go off what you show us.

Comment: @RobSpoor thank you. That's a nice advice

Comment: @Sweeper thank you for the explanation. Now i understand clearly

Comment: It's not possible with functions, but the overall idea isn't absolutely pointless. You can combine in such a way unary operators, predicates, even consumers.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, there is not an easy way to produce chained functions without specifically defining the input-output type for each of them and keeping the solution flexible.

A solution asks for a compromise by keeping the `Function` raw that would not enforce the types at the compile time and does not prevent runtime errors.

```java
private static Object flow(Object input, Function... functions) {
    Object temp = input;
    for (Function function : functions) {
        temp = function.apply(temp);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Usage:

```java
final int input = 1;
final String result = (String) flow(input,
    (Function<Integer, Integer>) integer -> integer * 10,
    integer -> ((double) integer / 4),
    decimal -> "c" + decimal,
    string -> List.of("a", "b", string),
    (Function<List<Double>, Set<Double>>) HashSet::new,
    (Function<Set<String>, String>) set -> String.join("-", set)
);
```

Result:

> ```
> a-b-c2.5
> ```